# Image sizes in LinearLayout

Tags: android, image, android-layout, imageview

I develop activity that shows two images. The idea is to place them horizontally, to place them in the center of the screen. Whatever their sizes are they should:

- fit both width and height (so they should be scaled to parent size, even to half of parent size)
- they should be placed in the center of the screen (horizontally) without any indent.

I create the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="center">

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
           android:layout_weight="1">

           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/image_one"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_test_the_universe_three" />

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:text="LEFT" />

           </RelativeLayout>

       </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_marginStart="4dp">

           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/image_two"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_test_the_universe_two" />

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="RIGHT"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

           </RelativeLayout>

       </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I place images with the height bigger than half of the screen the width of `ImageView` becomes greater than image's width. And when image's width is bigger than half of the screen `ImageView`'s height is too big.
Here are screenshots. `ImageView` sizes are colored with background color.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix it? How to make width of `ImageView` the same with the image's one?

Comment: Make your inner item `match_parent`. and use `scaleType` attribute in `ImageView`.

Comment: And probably consider using constraint layout, that is a very heavy view hierarchy.

Comment: @ADM , which inner item do you mean? And what scale type to use. As for me it still doesn't work. Probably you can provide an example?

Comment: It was long pause, sorry. Unfortunately, both comments do not help. `ConstraintLayout` doesn't influence on `ImageView` behavior - it still has the size that differs to image size. `ScaleType ()` defines which side the image will dock. So it's impossible to place any other element in the center of the image.

Comment: @JudeFernandes, sorry, perhaps you were right. `ConstraintLayout` really is the answer. There is another problem there, but I think it might be solved. So please put your comment as an answer to allow me to mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user seems to have solved it using a constraint layout which was the problem.

A Constraint Layout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use weight in LinearLayout .try below code.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_attach_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_image" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_attach_2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_image" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_attach_3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_image" />
        </LinearLayout>
```